# Issues when refactoring Kotlin Android project to Java: Error after removing 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' from Gradle files

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I created an Android project in Kotlin, and later on I decided to create the same project in Java. I used the Kotlin project as a base for the Java project. Initially, I had no problems when I used Kotlin for both projects. However, after I refactored the entire project from Kotlin to Java, I encountered some issues.

Specifically, I removed the following lines of code from the Gradle files:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
```

I also removed `kotlin.code.style=official` from the `gradle.properties` file.

After making these changes, I encountered an error, which reads:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Here is my `build.gradle (:app)` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    namespace 'com.d4rk.androidtutorials.java'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.d4rk.androidtutorials.java'
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 5
        versionName '2.0_a4'
        archivesBaseName = "${applicationId}-v${versionName}"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        resConfigs 'en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'hi', 'in', 'it', 'ja', 'ro', 'ru', 'tr', 'sv', 'bg', 'pl', 'uk'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    bundle {
        storeArchive {
            enable = true
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.KieronQuinn:MonetCompat:0.4.1'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Here is my other `build.gradle (Project Name)` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin' version '0.10.6' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.2' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's the `gradle.properties` file:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Why go back to Java though? Android has been Kotlin-first since 2019 https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first